# Error when I am using ehcache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache

I am new in use ehcache and I use settings below. When I set up ehcache 3 my project compile good, but when I sending query on endpoint, I got error:

```
2017-03-01 11:46:02,032 ERROR org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor : Application exception overridden by rollback error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheTimestampsRegion.put(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.preInvalidate(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.invalidateSpaces(ActionQueue.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
```

application.gradle

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'deliverypoint'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

ext {
    jodaTimeVersion = '2.9.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:$jodaTimeVersion")
    compile("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:7.0.55")
    compile group: 'org.jadira.usertype', name: 'usertype.jodatime', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.1.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.1.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.2.4.Final'
    compile(group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '3.0.5')

    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs')

    providedRuntime('javax.servlet:jstl')


    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-core', version: '1.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-security', version: '1.1.4.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.modelmapper.extensions', name: 'modelmapper-spring', version: '0.7.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps/google-maps-services
    compile group: 'com.google.maps', name: 'google-maps-services', version: '0.1.16'

//    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.2.1.Final' ) {
//        exclude group: 'net.sf.ehcache', module: 'ehcache' //by both name and group
//    }
//
//    compile group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.3.0'


    compile group: 'net.sf.ehcache', name: 'ehcache-core', version: '2.6.11'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.2.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.1.4.RELEASE'
    //    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
}

bootRun {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

Config hibernate:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
@Configuration
    public class DatabaseConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Bean
        public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap() {
            return applicationContext.getBeansOfType(DataSource.class);
        }

        /**
         * init startup resources like sql scripts
         *
         * @return DataSourceInitializer
         */

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
            hibernateTransactionManager.setAutodetectDataSource(false);
            return hibernateTransactionManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateMain(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        }

        public Properties hibernateProperties() {
            return new Properties() {
                {
                    setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("datasources.ddl-auto"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("datasources.hibernate.dialect"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("datasources.show-sql"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("datasources.format-sql"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.multiTenancy", env.getProperty("datasources.multiTenancyStrategy"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", env.getProperty("datasources.multiTenancyConnectionProvider"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", env.getProperty("datasources.multiTenancyIdentifierResolver"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", env.getProperty("datasources.default_schema"));
                    setProperty(AvailableSettings.USE_GET_GENERATED_KEYS, "true");

                    setProperty(AvailableSettings.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, "true");
                    setProperty(AvailableSettings.USE_QUERY_CACHE, "true");
                    setProperty(AvailableSettings.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
                    setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName","/ehcache.xml");
                }
            };
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryMain(Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap) {
            DataSource dataSource = dataSourceMap.get("datasourcemain");
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("io.default.deliverypoints");
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
        }        
    }
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" shared="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="billCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           eternal="true" timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

In main spring boot app i use @EnableCaching.
And annotation, which I use on entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="billCache")
@Cacheable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an abstract method exception because you need to wire up the provider between hibernate and ehcache.

The method for doing this is in the [documentation here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm).

In short, your config section for the hibernate properties also needs to include:

```
         setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not fixed my problem(

Comment: Fix this problem, but now have another problem: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.get(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: Again -- it's because you're missing something that should be wired in, or you've not properly applied annotations that are used as metadata for all this.

To look at that question one would probably need at least one of your entity classes for reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was that I forgot to exclude the JBoss' integrated org.hibernate module in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml while specifying a newer version of hibernate-core in the project's pom.xml. Therefore, the project mixed up the APIs of ehcache.

The src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml has to look like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```